# Read Columns of Text File as Numeric R ERROR

Tags: r, file

I have the following text file:

```
ENTERED: m

TAG TIME: 06/14/13 16:49:53 
DEPLOYED: 06/27/12 07:40:25 
TAG DELAY DAYS: 0  
INIT COUNTER: 460 AM

COM TIME: 03/29/00 01:17:06 
COM DELAY DAYS: 0 

0 33
1 33
2 129
3 44
4 129
5 5
```

with the columns after the header continuing on.  I want to read the columns `as.numeric` so, I call:

```
tag.raw <- read.table("tag612.txt", col.names = c("index", "light"), header = 
FALSE, skip = 10, colClasses = rep("numeric", 2))
```

and get the following ERROR:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : 
scan() expected 'a real', got '03/29/00'
```

When I omit `colClasses` the file is read without a problem, but with both columns read as factors.  What is the error and how do I read the columns following the header as integer/numeric?

Comment: I think you may need to increase the `skip` i.e .`skip = 12` or so.  BTW, based on your example showed, the `skip=10` is working fine for me.

Comment: As @akrun mentioned you may have extra line breaks in there such that skipping 10 lines does not get you to your actual data.